# where do the VMWare Workstation virtual disks get saved on the host?

Tags: vmware-workstation, virtual-drive

I can't seem to find the virtual disks from my virtual machine. I've looked in program files, and application data... Where do they get stored by default? I don't think I put them any place special, but I have to back them up now. I am reading my windows hard drive from a linux live CD, so I can't just start VMWare and ask it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For XP:

> C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\My
>   Documents\Virtual Machines

For Vista and later:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Virtual
>   Machines

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, it's ~/Virtual Machines.

(Note: Unlike on Windows as described by the other answer, VMWare on macOS does not put this folder in the Documents folder.)

Each Virtual Machine is a .vmwarevm bundle. Right-click on it and choose “Show Package Contents”. The hard drive image is inside, possibly divided into multiple files.